# Codeigniter: Display multiple columns from database as one

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wanted to display multiple column values from my database.

Using the query from model

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('projectskillslist ps');
$this->db->join('empskillslist s', 's.skillsID = ps.skillsID', 'left');
$this->db->join('projects p', 'p.projectID = ps.projectID', 'left');
$this->db->where('ps.projectID = 1');

$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
   return $result;
}
   return false;
```

And in my controller

```
$data['pSkills'] = $this->emp_model->view_projskills();
```

The query returns perfectly as expected:

[image]

Now in my view,

I wanted to call

```
Title: Project 1
SkillName: JAVA, PHP
```

So far, I have done this:

```
    foreach ($pSkills as $data) {
       echo $data['title'];
       echo $data['skillName'];
    }
```

And the result I am getting is

```
 Title: Project 1
    Skills: PHP
 Title: Project 2
    Skills: JAVA
```

It is a silly question indeed, I have already looked up and search for the same problem but I still no luck. I hope you can help me. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Have you checked print_r(data['pSkills']) is these return you the same result as PhpMyAdmin ?

Comment: @AkshayBajpei I have edited the result, my bad. And yes it was printing the same

Comment: @blakcat7 do you only have a formatting question, then? Because in your original question you seemed to be missing data.

Comment: Create one function or procedure for GetAllSkillbyProjectID and pass the projectID u wants to, ana call this function to SkillName:

Comment: @Shadow I guess it is formatting. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, but first order the result set by Project ID and Skill ID.

```
$this->db->order_by('projectID, skillID');
```

view

```
$lastProjectID = 0;
$p_skills = '';
$p_title = '';

foreach ($pSkills as $data) {

  if ($data['projectID'] !== $lastProjectID) {

    // if there's a title, printIt()
    if ($p_title !== '') {
      printIt($p_title, $p_skills);
    }

    // set new title and skill list
    $p_title = $data['title'];
    $p_skills = $data['skillName'];

    // remember last project 
    $lastProjectID = $data['projectID'];

  } else {

    // append skill name to skills
    $p_skills .= ", " . $data['skillName'];

  }
}

// end of foreach, if there's a title, printIt()
if ($p_title !== '') {
  printIt($p_title, $p_skills);
}

function printIt($title, $skills) {
  echo "Title: $title<br>";
  echo "SkillName: $skills<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried the code itself, didn't change anything it prints the Project Title, but the Skills just print out 0.

Comment: @blakcat7 My bad! Appending the skillname should be `$p_skills .= ", " . $data['skillName'];`. I used `+=` so it treated it like math addition.

Comment: Great! Worked well for now however it's printing the first skill twice.
Does it have to do with appending?

Project 1: Java, Java, PHP
When supposedly only  Java, PHP

Comment: @blakcat7 Yes, it's appending the first skill after it sets it when the $lastProjectID changes. It should have an `} else {` in there. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these step if it would can help..

Step 1: You have to concatenate projectID where GROUP_CONCAT will help.

Step 2. Perform your SQL query like below

`SELECT projectID, skillName, GROUP_CONCAT(projectID) AS projid FROM
    projectskillslist GROUP BY projid`

Step 3: To display it in a view , you can use PHP's explode() and iterate over that, like this if it would help..

```
    foreach ($pSkills as $row) {
    echo $row->title;
    echo explode(',', $row->skillName);
    /*
        or add below line of code  if it doesn't works

    */ 
     //echo str_replace(',', '<br />', $row->skillName);
}
```